# Less CSS Full list of Keywords and Syntax?

Tags: css, syntax, less, keyword

I'm a little lost here, I've gone to the LESS site and read the tutorials, but I can't figure out if the keywords listed on the LESS site under Guards, Mixin's, parametric mixin's etc are the FULL list of keywords | Syntax.

In other words is there a place I can find ALL the syntax | keywords used in LESS?
Or is it based on JavaScript? If so what Syntax is allowed from JavaScript?
Apologies if this question is "Duh" but the docs on the LESS site seem thin and I'm wondering if it's because I haven't connected the dots somehow.
Any real detailed tuts out there?

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

The [less.js website](http://lesscss.org/) has the most complete documentation of the latest version (1.3.0) at the moment.

It is crucially missing

1. Information about scoping - at least the description is incomplete/not clear and less.js doesn't consistently handle it
2. Information about creating selectors. e.g. you can do this (~"@{selector_var}") { display: block; } to write variables to selectors
3. Information about continuation arguments to mixins.. that you can do .a (@b, ...) { display: @arguments; } in order to allow calling the mixin with a variable number of arguments

The missing features above were added in 1.3.0 so will hopefully be added to the website soon.

There is also a plethora of help/information in [The less issues](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues) and I am trying to update/write more [information about the .net port dotless](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki).

Comment: First thanks for your response. OK, so I am not alone with this. I find it hard to understand why there would be a lack in documentation on this. It just stalls adoption of the work flow, or is to make sales on CSS preprocessor software I wonder? I will take a look at you notes below, and again many thanks I am sure it will help. So I can't really write my own LESS at this stage, or I gues I can but with limited syntax....

Comment: It's because less is done by people in there spare time. what language do you want to write 'your own one' in? there is already ports to c#, PHP and java..

Comment: What I meant was I am unable to write truly effective LESS withut more substantial documentation. I was looking for a documentation source but apparently the one on the site is IT. Thanks for your insights, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know which of the sites you looked, but it's maybe interesting for you: [less](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues) , [less 2](https://gist.github.com/674726), [less 3](http://nittygrittyjs.com/blog/why-less-is-a-pain-in-the-sass/), [less 4](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/09/an-introduction-to-less-and-comparison-to-sass/)